# Can't View Code or Script out Stored Procedures or Tables In Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Is there functionality in Azure SQL Data Warehouse similar to SQL Server's right-click -> Modify in SSMS for stored procedures?

Is there functionality in Azure SQL Data Warehouse similar to SQL Server Management Studio's right-click -> Script Table As... for tables?

I am running into inconveniences when trying to make modifications to my SP's and tables in my Azure Data Warehouse because I cannot do either of these things....I have to script out my SP/table and save that script somewhere so I can make modifications without having to rewrite it.

What I have tried:

In Visual Studio (2015 Enterprise, Update 1, Installed latest version of Data Tools yesterday), I right-click on the asset in the SQL Server Object Explorer and select "View Code"...the result of this is an error popup that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

In SSMS (2014 v12.0.4213.0) none of my tables show up in the Object Explorer, and if I right-click -> Modify on a stored procedure, I get the following error:

[image]

The only way right now that I can think to get the code is to write selects against `sys.sql_modules` and `sys.tables` et al.

Any insight would be great!

Comment: I also tried using SQL Server 2016 CTP3 and get the same results.

Comment: I mean SQL Server CTP3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Data Warehouse does not currently support SSMS. This is a high priority work item for the service and we are working to enable support soon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Do you know if there are any tools in the Visual Studio world to get the functionality mentioned above?

Comment: Not today there is not no.

Comment: The more recent versions of SSMS do support Azure SQL DW. But there is a bug in certain versions. I've posted about how to workaround the bug here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48820930/5070440

Answer (score 0):

I can script out objects from Visual Studio Community 2015 (which is free, as in beer).

I've got the Azure DW registered in SQL Server Object Explorer - which is a bit clunky if you're used to SSMS - and can script an object by right-clicking and selecting "View Code".

If you change anything, you generally need to refresh the tree at the *database* level before the right-click functions work again.

Comment: I still get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in VS 2015 Enterprise...Azure SDK v2.8.2.1

Answer (score -1):

For SSDT support, including view code, you must be running the preview version.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: I downloaded and installed 14.0.60413.0 (April 2016 preview) and I still get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" from View Code in Visual Studio 2015. Am I doing something wrong? Should that work?

Comment: I believe the reason you are hitting this issue is because your default database is set to master and not to your user database in SQL Server Object Explorer. Give that a go.

Comment: As @JRJ said it appears in certain versions of SSMS there's a bug that requires the user to have master database access since you can't currently change the default database property of a login in Azure SQL. I've added the workaround for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48820930/5070440