# Cannot view object schema Azure Datawarehouse

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ddl, azure-synapse

Attempting to view the a `view` or `procedure`:

[image]

from SQL Server Management Studio 17.4 in Azure SQL Datawarehouse notes the error:

[image]

I can however, delete and create any object that I want.

How can I work to ensure I can view the objects definition?

**UPDATED**

Concerning setting the options in SSMS to SQL Datawarehouse, there is not that option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please change this setting under Tools... Options. That should resolve the error. I wish we didn't have to change this but at lease we have a workaround.

[image: scripting options]

In SSMS 17.5 there are a few more options. You can have it automatically detect what type of database you're connected to and script accordingly. Or you can force it to script for a particular database type like the following screenshot.

[image]

It appears there is a bug in certain versions of SSMS (such as 17.5) where if the DW user isn't also a user in the master database then scripting fails. The easy fix for this is having the server admin connect to the master database and run:

```
CREATE USER MyUserNameHere FROM LOGIN MyUserNameHere;
```

Comment: I do no have these options, is this another version of SSMS? I am on 17.5

Comment: @Sauron I updated my answer for 17.5. Thanks for mentioning it was different than my old screenshot.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that in some versions of SSMS there's a bug that requires the user be a user of the master database.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you're seeing this. I've been able to repro this on SSMS 17.4 and 17.5. We are looking at this now.

This seems to be a defect in the upgrade path for 17.5 as this should be supported without having to change the script settings. We are investigating this and will try to get an update out as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you, within Azure Active Directory, we are an `OWNER` on that server so should be able to view everything

Comment: Where is that located?

Comment: @Matt - I have the same problem and have had it for two months - really problematic. Do you have a fix or a work-around?